# Answer helps you understand, but is very awkwardly worded

Tags: discussion, answers

There is a question I just saw that was very interesting to me. A user posted an answer that clearly had a lot of thought put into it - it's six paragraphs long. After reading it 15-20 times, I finally understood what they meant and how it answers the question. It is a correct answer... but it isn't a good answer. It's too difficult to actually grok. I also do not know how to edit it to make it better... short of literally rewriting the whole thing just based on a skeleton.

Is it OK to take this user's idea and write a new answer in a way that is more understandable, or should I just write comments on that user's answer asking him to rewrite his?

Comment: Sounds like half of my answers...

Comment: Can you share the link with us?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you totally edit it (as in rewriting), you're jeopardizing that user's reputation; they're the ones that could potentially receive negative impact from your efforts. I'd be pretty ticked off if someone did that to one of my answers, and would most likely roll the edit back.

If the answer is that unclear, a better solution would probably be to either comment on that answer to try to get it improved, or write your own instead. If you feel guilty about doing the latter, you could always make it community wiki so you can't gain any rep from it. If you do so, it's always polite to mention the other answer that you're basing yours on as well.

Comment: It's not just polite to mention the source, it's required by the cc-by-sa license used on SO.

Comment: @Angew: Depends on how complete the complete rewrite was. If only the underlying basic idea is kept, it gets really tenuous calling that a derived work. Though better safe than sorry, being polite by acknowledging the inspiration.

Comment: @Deduplicator Not sure how it legally works, but I generally work as if I was writing a paper just more relaxed: If I base the majority of my answer on an existing source I will cite it, so I'd definitely cite it even if not a single sentence of the source was still intact at the end. But not sure what's actually required, would be interesting.

Comment: I went with upvoting the original answer and writing a new one, then later saw that a 3rd user wrote a new answer that I thought was just as good as mine so I deleted mine and upvoted that one too. Figure that checks off all the boxes - original answer got an upvote, and there exists an answer to the question that I find more than satisfactory.

Answer (score 21):

It happened to one of my answers.

Another user modified my answer substantially, enough to make it their answer. I rolled back the answer and asked them to create another answer. They did. Strangely enough, their answer got accepted by the OP. In the end, I think that was the right thing for both of us. They got credit for their answer. Had I left my answer alone after their modification, my answer would have most likely been accepted by the OP but then, that wouldn't really have been my answer.

Given that experience, my recommendation is to go ahead and create your answer. Give due credit to the other answer. Let the community decide which one is the better answer.

Comment: It's probably not a common situation, but I wonder if SO could flag that you're rewriting the answer all out and it might be better to post another answer with attribution.

Comment: @twotwotwo, If they have the resources to pull that off that would be great but I don't have a gut feel for the level of intelligence that has to be built into that code.

Comment: I agree: rareish and seems like it could be a pain to implement.

Answer (score 5):

Try to leave a comment to the OP (or contact them otherwise) to point out that you could probably rewrite their answer to be way more comprehensible than it currently is. Accompany with judicious praise for the existing answer. ;) Perhaps the OP is aware of the convoluted nature of their answer and just can't get around to rewrite it themselves. In that case they'd probably be happy to replace it with your version, if that is indeed better.

If that doesn't work, you're always free to post your own answer. I'd clarify that user X's answer really made the pieces click, but that you're trying to express this in a different way for the benefit of everyone else, since you recognise that the original answer may require a bit more background than could be expected of beginners yada yada (add praise)...

Just be civil and respectful. You only shouldn't replace the OP's content without express consent nor try to sell content as yours that actually isn't.